# Communicating between client js and server node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a single page app that I'm trying to build and was wondering how to run a script in node when a button is clicked to return data to the client side.

Would I do this with something like this:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

With the theUrl being the address of an express instance running that is waiting for this request to respond with the results of the node script? Such as 127.0.0.1:3030 or some other port that I chose for it to listen on?

Am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

The express hello world example is probably a good place to start...

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Comment: I understand express. I was wondering about communicating from client to server